# Applescript: Parse from Mail

Tags: applescript

I am looking for an applescript which fetches thru my Mails to get the desired results:

Subject of the E-Mail: Registrierung fuer die Badener Hochzeitstage - 2587 (here I need the number)

Contents of the E-Mail I need are the Name after "Frau/Herr/Firma" until the next "space"

I had an error in my php/mysql code therefor I do not have this in my database, so I need to parse around 400 E-Mails.

```
tell application "Mail"

set theMessages to message 1 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Die Badenerhochzeitstage" whose subject begins with "Registrierung fuer"
set theContent to content of theMessages

set someData to paragraphs of theContent
repeat with someData in theContent

    if someData begins with "Firma" then
        set theURL to paragraph of someData
    else
        set theURL to paragraph 10 of theContent -- this works but this line can change weekly
    end if
end repeat

end tell
```

Here I have tried but as result I just get some lines and not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   set TID to text item delimiters
set myRecords to {}

set outputFile to quoted form of (POSIX path of ((path to desktop as text) & "LaunchAgent_Alert.txt")) -- represents "MacHD:Users:david:Desktop:result.txt"

tell application "Mail" to set theMessages to every message of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Badener Hochzeitstage" whose subject begins with "Registrierung fuer"

repeat with aMessage in theMessages
   tell application "Mail" to set {mSubject, mContent} to {subject, content} of aMessage
   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-"
   set mSubject to text item 2 of mSubject

   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "Herr/Frau/Firma "
   set mContent to first word of (text item 2 of mContent)

   set end of myRecords to {mSubject & return & mContent & return & return}

end repeat

set myRecords to myRecords as text
do shell script "echo " & myRecords & " > " & outputFile

set text item delimiters to TID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
set theAccount to "Die Badenerhochzeitstage"
set subjectText to "Registrierung fuer"
set subjectSearch to "-"
set contentSearch to "Frau/Herr/Firma"
set theResults to {}

tell application "Mail"
    try
        set theMessages to messages of mailbox "INBOX" of account theAccount whose subject begins with subjectText
        if theMessages is {} then
            display dialog "No Messages were found which begins with:" & return & subjectText buttons {"OK"} default button 1
            return
        end if

        repeat with aMessage in theMessages
            tell aMessage
                set theSubject to subject
                set theContent to content
            end tell
            set theNumber to my getFirstWordAfterSearchText(subjectSearch, theSubject)
            set theWord to my getFirstWordAfterSearchText(contentSearch, theContent)
            set end of theResults to {theNumber, theWord}
        end repeat
    on error theError
        display dialog theError buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        return
    end try
end tell
return theResults

(*============== SUBROUTINES =================*)
on getFirstWordAfterSearchText(searchString, theText)
    try
        set {tids, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, searchString}
        set textItems to text items of theText
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tids
        return (first word of (item 2 of textItems))
    on error theError
        return ""
    end try
end getFirstWordAfterSearchText
```

Comment: great minds think alike ;) http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=39630  I'm not sure if the name is 1 word or more.

Comment: That's funny adayzdone. He did say up-to-the-space so that's word 1 to me. In any case I'm glad he's getting help.